# Is the following a 2D array?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, malloc

I wanted to dynamically allocate 2D array using pointers.

```
int *arr = (int *)malloc(rows * cols * sizeof(int));
```

this works, but is this single pointer array technically a 2D array?

Thank you!

Comment: any array can be n-dimensional if it's the correct size. An array of 16 ints can technically be treated as 4x4 2D array, if you don't mind the syntax

Comment: Technically C doesn't have 2D arrays, so the point is moot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's technically just a 1D array. But it can be used as a 2D array by calculating the indexes based on row-major ordering:

```
int index = row * cols + col;
int val = arr[index];
```

This is what goes on behind the scenes when you declare a 2D array:

```
int arr[rows][cols]
int val = arr[row][col];
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is the following a 2D array?

```
int *arr = (int *)malloc(rows * cols * sizeof(int));
```

No. `arr` is a pointer.  That pointer is  initialized with a memory address suitable to store a 2D array.

---

> I wanted to dynamically allocate 2D array using pointers.

**It depends on the kind of "2D"**

The idea of "2D array" is often used loosely.  Let us explore some possible interpretations.

To allocate a pointer to a 2D array, use the following. If `rows,cols` are constants or code is C99, or C11 with *variable length arrays*:

```
int (*arr_true)[rows][cols] = malloc(sizeof *arr_true);
(*arr_true)[0][0] = this;
(*arr_true)[0][1] = that;
// etc.
```

To allocate memory for a 2D array with `cols` width.  If `cols` is constant or code is C99, or C11 with *variable length arrays*:

```
int *arr_mem[cols] = malloc(sizeof *arr_mem * rows);
arr_mem[0][0] = this;
arr_mem[0][1] = that;
// etc.
```

To allocate memory for an array with `row*cols` elements.

```
int *arr_flat = malloc(sizeof *arr_flat *rows * cols);
arr_flat[0 *cols + 0] = this;
arr_flat[0 *cols + 1] = that;
// etc.
```

To allocate an array of pointers to pointers of `int`

```
int *arr_classic = malloc(sizeof *arr_classic *rows);
for (size_t r = 0; r<rows; r++) {
  arr_classic[r] = malloc(sizeof *arr_classic[r] *cols);
}
arr_classic[0][0] = this;
arr_classic[0][1] = this;
// etc.
```

---

**Improvement idea for size calculation.**

Consider the math used to calculate size.  If `rows,cols` were `int`, `rows * cols` could overflow the `int` range leading to *undefined behavior*.  This same calculation done with `size_t` might not mathematically overflow and should be preferred.

In the end, `malloc(size_t sz)` expects a `size_t`,

```
int *arrA = malloc(rows * cols * sizeof(int)); // possible int*int overflow
int *arrB = malloc(sizeof(int) * rows * cols); // preferred
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int *arr = (int *)malloc(rows * cols * sizeof(int));
```

`arr` is a pointer to a memory location with `rows * cols * sizeof(int)` allocated bytes.
It doesn't matter for the language what you interpret the memory location as, it is up to you. 1D array, 2D array, string, etc. In C semantics it would probably be a 1D array but that is still not the entire truth since it's up to you to interpret and manage the memory how you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

No, a pointer is *never* an array. See section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/).

You can use this technique to allocate a chunk of memory that you can then treat like a 2-dimensional array, with the pointer `arr` point to its initial element.  A simpler and better way to write it is:

```
int *arr = malloc(rows * cols * sizeof (*arr));
```

This allocates a 1-dimensional array of `rows*cols` `int` elements. You can't use `arr[i][j]` notation to index it; you need to compute the index yourself: `arr[i * rows + j]`.

If you want to allocate a *dynamic* 2-dimensional array (or, more precisely, a data structure that acts like one), you need to create an array of `int**` pointers, and initialize each element to point to a newly allocated array of `int` elements. (And then you need to clean it all up with you're done with it.)  For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    int cols = 20;
    int rows = 10;

    // Allocate memory for an array of pointers to rows
    int **arr_2d = malloc(rows * sizeof *arr_2d);
    if (arr_2d == NULL) {
        abort(); // horribly crude error handling
    }

    // Allocate memory for each row
    for (int row = 0; row < rows; row ++) {
        int *arr_1d = malloc(cols * sizeof *arr_1d);
        if (arr_1d == NULL) {
            abort(); // horribly crude error handling
        }
        arr_2d[row] = arr_1d;
    }

    // Assign data 
    for (int row = 0; row < rows; row ++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < cols; col ++) {
            arr_2d[row][col] = row*col;
        }
    }

    // Dump data
    for (int row = 0; row < rows; row ++) {
        printf("Row %2d:", row);
        for (int col = 0; col < cols; col ++) {
            printf(" %3d", arr_2d[row][col]);
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }

    // Deallocate each row
    for (int row = 0; row < rows; row ++) {
        free(arr_2d[row]);
    }

    // Deallocate the array of row pointers
    free(arr_2d);
}
```

Comment: Guess the DV didn't care to comment so I'm going to give you +1 to balance things out. Because I see no errors in this answer.